# Is there any way to define pi from my code?

Tags: python, function

```
def sphereVolume(radius,pi):
    pi=3.14
    volume = (4/3) *(pi*radius**3)
    return volume

radius = float(input("Type the radius of a sphere :"))

print(sphereVolume(radius,pi))
```

I run this code and it says " pi is not defined"

What should I do ?

Comment: `pi` is a local variable to the function. If you want it accessible globally, define it *before*  the function. But secondly, you define `pi` as a function parameter. That is strange to do, since we know it is a constant. So remove the parameter, as otherwise it will still shadow the global `pi`.

Comment: `math.pi` would resolve your problem differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `math` library in Python. Try the following

```
import math
def sphereVolume(radius):
    return (4/3)*(math.pi*(radius**3))
```

If for some particular reason you want a specific precision in your volume function you can use the `round` function which is in-built.

Answer (score 0):

python says pi is not defined because it's just a local variable for the function sphereVolume, in other words, pi is only recognizable inside this function.

Because pi has always the same value, it will be better to not put it as parameter.

My suggestion:

```
# here pi is declared as global variable
pi=3.14

def sphereVolume(radius):

    volume = (4/3) *(pi*radius**3)
    return volume

radius = float(input("Type the radius of a sphere :"))

print(sphereVolume(radius))
```